What does this error statement I get from the Remix Vyper plugin mean?
I'm making a contract in vyper that gets a flashloan from aave, swaps at uniswap, then at curve finance, and then repays the loan. However, when I try to compile the code using the Vyper Compiler plugin on Remix, I keep getting the same error Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'split') and I have no idea what this means. I'm not using the .split() method anywhere in my code so i have no idea what line this error is on or what it means. I tried to figure out if it was something with my implementation of the Uniswap and Curve routers, all the parameters I've fed look right to me based on the documentation. Please help, I have no idea where this error is even coming from, how to fix it, or even what it means. Thank you to whoever sees this.
Here is my code so far:
#pragma version ^0.3.3
"""
@title Dual Swap Smart Contract using Uniswap and Curve with getting a flash loan from AAVE
@license UNLICENSED
@author Salmon46
@notice Vyper implementation of flash loan smart contract with swapping
"""

from vyper.interfaces import ERC20

# set constants to desired level
MAX_PARAMS_LEN: constant(uint256) = 32
MAX_ASSETS_LEN: constant(uint256) = 32

#initialize resource variables
POOL: constant(address) = 0x2f39d218133AFaB8F2B819B1066c7E434Ad94E9e #aave pool
UNISWAP_V3_ROUTER: constant(address) =  0xE592427A0AEce92De3Edee1F18E0157C05861564 #Uniswap v3 Router
from "https://github.com/curvefi/curve-router-ng/blob/master/contracts/Router.vy" import CryptoPoolETH #Curve Router

# token addresses
USDC: constant(address) = 0xA0b86991c6218b36c1d19D4a2e9Eb0cE3606eB48
WETH9: constant(address) = 0xC02aaA39b223FE8D0A0e5C4F27eAD9083C756Cc2

#initialize owner
owner: immutable(address)

@external
def __init__(_owner: address):
    owner = _owner

@external
def flash_call(
    _amount: uint256, #Prolly like 1000
):
    """
    @notice Make flash loan call to pool
    @dev Uses raw_call, since uint16 is not supported in vyper
    @param _asset Address of asset to borrow
    @param _amount Amount of asset to borrow (raw)
    @param _params Arbitrary params to pass to the receiver
    @param _referral_code Optional Aave referral code
    """
    _receiver_address: constant(address) = self
    _asset: constant(address) = USDC
    _params: Bytes[MAX_PARAMS_LEN] = ""
    
    raw_call(
        POOL,
        _abi_encode(
            _receiver_address,
            _asset,
            _amount,
            _params,
            method_id=method_id("flashLoanSimple(address,address,uint256,bytes,uint16)") #Last param is referral code and that's optional
        )
    )

@public
def swapWithUniswap(amountIn: uint256):
    #Approve Uniswap router to spend USDC
    ERC20(USDC).approve(UNISWAP_V3_ROUTER, amountIn)

    #initialize params
    uniswapPoolFee: constant(unint256) = 3000
    amountOutMinimum: uint256 = 0 #REMEMBER TO CHANGE
    sqrtPriceLimitX96: uint256 = 0
    receiver_address: constant(address) = self

    amountOut = raw_call(
        UNISWAP_V3_ROUTER,
        _abi_encode(
            USDC,
            WETH9,
            uniswapPoolFee,
            receiver_address,
            block.timestamp,
            amountIn,
            amountOutMinimum, #This is amountOutMinimum...REMEBER TO CHANGE
            sqrtPriceLimitX96,
            method_id=method_id("exactInputSingle((address, address, uint24, address, uint256, uint256, uint256, uint160))")
        ),
    )

    return amountOut

@public
def swapWithCurve(amount_In: uint256):
    #Approve Curve Router to spend Wrapped ether
    ERC20(WETH9).approve(CryptoPoolETH, amount_In)

    #initalize paramss
    _route: address[11] = [
            '0xc02aaa39b223fe8d0a0e5c4f27ead9083c756cc2',   # initial token: wETH
            '0x7f86bf177dd4f3494b841a37e810a34dd56c829b',   # pool1: TricryptoUSDC (USDC, wBTC, wETH)
            '0xa0b86991c6218b36c1d19d4a2e9eb0ce3606eb48',   # output token: USDC
            '0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000', 
            '0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000', 
            '0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000',
            '0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000',
            '0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000',
            '0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000',
            '0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000',
            '0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000',
        ]
    _swap_params: uint256[5][5] = [
        [2, 0, 1, 3, 3], #1st element is token index of WETH in the TricryptoUSDC pool. 2nd element is the token index of USDC in the same pool. 3rd element is the type of swap --just a standard token exchange--. 4th element is the type of pool --using a TriCrypto pool. 5th elemnt is how many coins are in the pool --3 coins.
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], #Only doing 1 swap so that's why these are all empty
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
    ]
    _expected: uint256 = 0 #Same thing as amountOutMinimum...ALSO REMEMBER TO CHANGE
    _pools: address[5] = [
        '0x7f86bf177dd4f3494b841a37e810a34dd56c829b', #TricryptoUSDC pool address
        '0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000',
        '0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000',
        '0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000',
        '0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000'
    ]
    _receiver_address: constant(address) = self

    CryptoPoolETH.exchange(
        _route,
        _swap_params,
        amount_In,
        _expected, 
        _pools, #Empty for pools since we are only using 1 pool aka only need this parameter for swap type 3
        _receiver_address
    )

@external
def executeOperation(
    _asset: address,
    _amount: uint256,
    _premium: uint256,
    _initiator: address, 
    _params: Bytes[MAX_PARAMS_LEN]
) -> bool: 
    """
    @notice Executes logic with borrowed asset and set approval
    @dev This method is called by the Aave Pool
    @param _asset Addresses of asset borrowed
    @param _amount Amount of asset borrowed (raw)
    @param _premium Premium owed for asset borrowed (raw)
    @param _initiator Address of the initiator of the flash loan
    @param _params Arbitrary params passed by the initiator
    @return True if execution success
    """
    # conduct logic
    postUniValue = swapWithUniswap(_amount)
    swapWithCurve(postUniValue)

    # approve transfer back to pool
    amount_owed: uint256 = _amount + _premium
    ERC20(_asset).approve(POOL, amount_owed)      

    return True

